# Trouble using Amazon EC2 for remote Mongo database.

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongoose, meanjs

I have a multi-page mean.js app, that I need to host. I've tried the steps in this guide https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-mean-app-to-amazon-ec2-part-2 but when I try to run a local version of my app using a remote version of mongodb on an amazon EC2 instance, I run into the following error.

```
    C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions
    at C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:169:23
    at C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1499:46
    at C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1632:20
    at C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\command_cursor.js:152:16
    at C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1196:16
    at C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1905:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:453:41)
    at C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:488:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\responses\mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:446:20)
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:207:13)
    at emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\CS\BOROWR\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:440:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
```

In terms of my code, the only thing I've changed is replacing the line

```
module.exports = {
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/borowr-dev',
```

with

```
module.exports = {
    db: 'mongodb://MY_EC2_URL.com:27017/borowr-dev',
```

I previously tried updating my version of connect-mongo from 0.4.2 to 1.1.0, which caused other problems. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the security group on your MongoDB instance allowing traffic on port 27017 from your local IP address?

Comment: This looks interesting: https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/issues/65#issuecomment-115995801 I wonder, if you clean out node_modules and do NPM install again, does it work remotely or break locally? I suspect you may be getting different versions of things.

Comment: In response to Matt. Yes, I set the inbound port 27017 to allow all ips in the security group tab of my ec2 instance. 
Tanner, I will try to update mongod and connect-mongo and see what happens.